# How to change a datatype for a field

Tags: 6

How do I change a data type for a field in a table?

To change the field name we can use [db_change_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql-common.inc/function/db_change_field/6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same function can be used to change the type of the field.

Suppose you are the following field defined for the "foo" schema.

```
$schema['foo'] = array(
  'fields' => array(
    'bar' => array('type' => 'int', 'not null' => TRUE)
  ),
  'primary key' => array('bar')
);
```

You can change its type to "serial" using the following code:

```
db_drop_primary_key($ret, 'foo');
db_change_field($ret, 'foo', 'bar', 'bar',
  array('type' => 'serial', 'not null' => TRUE),
  array('primary key' => array('bar')));
```

The call to `db_drop_primary_key()` is necessary because the field is a primary key; for compatibility with any database engine, it is suggested to first remove the primary keys, the indexes, and the unique keys before to edit them.

If in the call to `db_change_field()`, the third and the fourth parameters contain the same value, then you are not changing the field name.

The documentation for the function contains the following text:

> Change a field definition.
>
> IMPORTANT NOTE: To maintain database portability, you have to explicitly recreate all indices and primary keys that are using the changed field.

To notice that the first line doesn't say "change a field name"; it says "change a field definition," and the field name is included in the field definition.

Answer (score 1):

For DRUPAL 7
There are 4 places that you have to change when the above answer does not work or you really want to do this by hand. To change my INT file into an VARCHAR 64 I did like this:

1. Change the database table for the field. I created a field with the same name with txt at the end (the value field). Since text fields have a format I created also a format field. I copied the content from one value field to the new one, and deleted the old one. Then I renamed the txt one back to only value.
2. Change the revision table for the field as above
3. Change the field_config table, I checked other fields that were txt and copied most of it's contents. The tricky part is the blob field of course
4. Change the field_instance table, here you have to check the blob field and change the widget part

For fields that where created by you with the UI this is sufficient. For module fields you have to check the database definitions and update them. This is tricky stuff, so be sure to make the changes in a dev environment, copy the slqs and then do a fast change in your actual site.

Hope this helps someone.